# JSON data From phpFox ajax call?

Tags: ajax, json, phpfox

How to return JSON data in `phpFox`, `ajaxCall`?
In `phpFox` i am using `$.ajaxCall('samplemodule.function' 'data=test');`

How to return JSON data? and how to process on that data inside any js function.

Answer (score 2):

In the file /module/samplemodule/component/ajax/ajax.class.php, create a function named function (per your example).

Inside that function, use this to return data back to the JS you're making your ajax call in:

```
$this->call('var myJSONObject=' . json_encode('Your Data Here'));
```

Or send something more interesting, instead of data=test, lets do userId= (their user ID) like this:

```
$iUserId = Phpfox::getLib('request')->getInt('userId');
$aUser = $aUser = Phpfox::getService('user')->getUser($iUserId);
$this->call('var aUser =' . json_encode($aUser));
```

Now you have aUser set up as a JSON object with the user's info loaded in to it.

Comment: This returns 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: aUser'

Comment: in the ajax.class.php you dont need to getLib('request'), you can just $this->get('userId') provided that you made the ajax call with $.ajaxCall('blah.blah', 'userId=321');

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are confused as to how an ajax call works. In an ajax call your JS code will send a request to the server and continue executing the remaining javascript code, regardless of what happens in the server. So what you do is to return code from the ajax call:

> JS Code -> Ajax Call -> Process in server -> JS Code

In that logic aboce, the last JS Code would call a javascript function with info taken from the "Process in server" stage, you can call a function and pass params to that functions, these params may be JSON objects if you wish.

I made a sample of how to do this in phpfox (ajax call + call JS function with JSON param) [here](https://github.com/purefan/foxadvisor/tree/master/ajax-1), hope it helps